# Is there a psql client config file analogous to $HOME/my.cnf for mysql ?

Tags: postgresql, psql

That is, a local file on the client machine with default "host", "port", "user" values, etc., so that I don't have to enter them on the command line each time?

Comment: The right answer is: [Connection Service File](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgservice.html), Usage: `psql service={ini_section_name} [other-options]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [password file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-pgpass.html) with lines like:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

If you always log into the same host:db:port:user then this will make it:

```
*:*:*:*:mypassword
```

Comment: Note that this still requires specifying host, user, port, and database when making a connection, the file can only ever make the password unnecessary.

Answer (score 8):

You can either define one (or several ) alias to `psql` with the proper arguments for user, database, host.  Or set some [environment values](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-envars.html).